# Append text to biblatex footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Does biblatex allow to append arbitrary comments to footnote citations?

For example, I now have this code:

```
Lorem ipsum.\autocite[2]{foobar}
```

And it gives this at the bottom of the page:

> Foobar, p. 2.

The result I'm after is:

> Foobar, p. 2. What a cute little comment.

Where should I put "What a cute little comment." for it to appear in the footnote?

Comment: `\footnote{\textcite[2]{foobar}. What a cute little comment.}`?

Comment: Worked. Thank you, egreg. I had to replace `\textcite` with `\cite` though, because the particular citation style I use disliked it.

Comment: You could also use `\autocite[\pno~2. What a cute little comment.]{foobar}` (`biblatex` drops the page prefix if it finds that the postnote is not a number, we have to re-insert it manually via´\pno`, use `\ppno` for more than one page.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that in this case you don't have a footnote citation, but a real footnote that happens to contain a citation.

A command such as `\footcite` (which your bibliographic style translates `\autocite` to) is meant for just a citation.

So I think it's preferable to make your intentions clear:

```
\footnote{\cite[2]{foobar}. A nice comment follows.}
```

One might object that `\autocite` allows for simply changing the style from footnote citations to in-text ones, but in this case a comment wouldn't find its place naturally in the text flow.